# How to render new instances of an object in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have an array of images and am rendering each one as a card object that can be dragged around. I don't want to render every single one as this causes performance issues. At the moment I am using a forEach loop to render all of them but how would I render say two until one is deleted. Once one is deleted I'd render a new instance underneath the currently visible card. I don't need this exact implementation but can someone point me on the right approach.

```
import Photos
import SwiftUI

var imageToDelete = [PHAsset]()

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            // Here is where I'm rendering the card
            ZStack{
                ForEach(imageObjectGroup){ card in
                    CardView(card: card).padding(8)
                }
            }.zIndex(1.0)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

// You can ignore this I am converting the array item (PHAsset) to a UIImage so I can render it

func getAssetThumbnail(asset: PHAsset) -> UIImage {
    let manager = PHImageManager.default()
    let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
    var thumbnail = UIImage()
    option.isSynchronous = true
    manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 350, height: 350), contentMode: .aspectFit, options: option, resultHandler: {(result, info)->Void in
        thumbnail = result!
    })
    return thumbnail
}

// Card Object
struct CardView: View{
    @State var card: ImageObject
    let cardGradient = Gradient(colors: [Color.black.opacity(0), Color.black.opacity(0.5)])
    var body: some View{
        ZStack(alignment: .leading){
            Image(uiImage: getAssetThumbnail(asset: card.image)).resizable().padding(8)
            LinearGradient(gradient: cardGradient, startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
            
            HStack {
                Image("yes").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit).frame(width: 150).opacity(Double(card.x/10 - 1))
                Spacer()
                Image("nope").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit).frame(width: 150).opacity(Double(card.x/10 * -1 - 1))
            }
        //ZStack follows the coordinates of the card model
        }.offset(x: card.x, y: card.y).rotationEffect(.init(degrees: card.degree)).gesture(
            //Gesture recognizer updates coordinate values
            DragGesture().onChanged { value in
                card.x = value.translation.width
                card.y = value.translation.height
                card.degree = 7 * (value.translation.width > 0 ? 1 : -1)
            }
            //When user stops dragging
            .onEnded { value in
                withAnimation(.interpolatingSpring(mass: 1.0, stiffness: 50, damping: 8, initialVelocity: 0)){
                        switch value.translation.width {
                            case 0...100:
                                card.x = 0; card.degree = 0; card.y = 0
                            // Keep
                            case let x where x > 100:
                                card.x = 200; card.degree = 12
                            case (-100)...(-1):
                                card.x = 0; card.degree = 0; card.y = 0;
                            // Delete
                            case let x where x < -100:
                                card.x = -200; card.degree = -12
                                print(card.image)
                                imageToDelete.append(card.image)
                                PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges( {
                                PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets(imageToDelete as NSFastEnumeration)},
                                completionHandler: {
                                    success, error in NSLog("Deletion prompt complete")
                                })
                            default: card.x = 0; card.y = 0
                        }
                }
            }
        ).cornerRadius(8)
    }
}
```

Comment: how about using `LazyVStack` , does this still cause performance issues?

Comment: Yes because I size it smaller for performance reasons but the LazyVStack forces it to fill up all the available space

Comment: Another thing I should mention is that the cards are stacked on top of each other so I think a lazy stack would still render them all since they're all visible in the view just on top of each other

Answer (score 0):

`VStack` gonna render every view inside, you need to use one of lazy views:

1. List, it's wrapper for `UITableView`. Advantages of this one is ability to use many table view features, like removing cells with a swipe, reordering, etc, but it's hard to customize if the way you won't sometime, like when you'd like to remove separators, etc. Check out more in [apple lists tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation). I suggest you passing all apple tutorials because they are very good

```
List {
    ForEach(imageObjectGroup){ card in
        CardView(card: card).padding(8)
    }.zIndex(1.0)
}
```

2. Second way is `LazyVStack` wrapped in `ScrollView`. It works just like `VStack` but loads cells in a lazy way. Check out more in [this article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-lazy-load-views-using-lazyvstack-and-lazyhstack)

```
ScrollView {
    LazyVStack {
        ForEach(imageObjectGroup){ card in
            CardView(card: card).padding(8)
        }.zIndex(1.0)
    }
}
```

p.s. I'm not sure why're you wrapping your card with `ZStack`, it's redundant here

Comment: I've tried LazyVStack but it has a unique sizing property that alters the size of the card images. I currently have them sized smaller for performance reasons but LazyVStack forces the item to take up all of the width making the app lag.

Comment: @Sachu if you wanna get suggestion of how to fix your lags, you need to update your example to be easy to run just by copy-paste. First suggestion is that `getAssetThumbnail` can take much time, because you're fetching an image from store in synchronous way each time view gets re-rendered, you should move this logic to view model or a helper class

Comment: That's a good point, I'll try and convert the PHAssets to UIImages and store them prior to rendering them to improve performance.